# Problema para consultar datos con mongoose

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy intentando implementar los Schemas con mongoose en nodejs, pero tengo un problema, una simple consulta con find() me devuelve vacio

[image: la sesctructura de mi schema]

aca les dejo la ruta que estoy tratando de usar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: para esto, no me devuelve ningun tipo de error, solo me arroja vacio nada mas

Comment: Bienvenidx a SOes. Como sugerencia, el código se comparte como texto: a quien revise en móvil se lo complicas; al que quiera replicar tu problema lo pones a transcribir algo que sólo tienes que copiar y pegar; al que tenga algún grado de discapacidad se lo pones más difícil. Procura siempre compartir código como texto.

Comment: ¿Y la colección contiene documentos?

Comment: Por favor, no publiques capturas de pantalla de código, publica el código como tal (texto).

Comment: [Dices](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/379890/problema-para-consultar-datos-con-mongoose#comment680708_379902) que si usas directamente MongoDB, todo funciona bien. ¿Podrías agregar el código que dices que funciona bien? Saludos

Answer (score 2):

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose')
let Schema = mongoose.Schema

let UsuarioSchema = new Schema({
    codigo:{type: Number},
    nombres:{type: String, trim:true },
    celular:{type: Number},
    email:{type: String, require: true, unique:true,match: /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i },
    direccion:{type: String, trim:true },
    password:{type: String,required: true,match: /(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9]+).*/,minlength: 5},
    edad:{type: Number},
    ciudad:{type: String},
    estado:{type: Boolean},
    ultimoLogin:{type: Date, default:Date.now()},
    creacionUsuario: {type: Date,default: new Date()}
})

let Usuario = mongoose.model('usuario', UsuarioSchema,'usuario')

module.exports = Usuario
```

asi pude solucionar el problema, tenia que nuevamente declarar la coleccion en el mongoose.model, en ningun tutorial o solucion vi que hicieran algo asi, pero funciono bien , gracias por sus respuestas

Answer (score 0):

Bien un par de cosas antes para revisar:

1. Tenés datos ya cargados en la base?
2. Para descartar que no le estés pegando al endpoind ***/prueba*** ponete un `console.log('entre a la busqueda de prueba')` antes de hacer el find
3. Está bien tu conexion de base de datos? Pudiste interactuar con ella antes?
4. Importaste tu schema donde tenes el `get`?

Ahora lo que noté es que no hace falta que pongas las **{}** dentro del **find**. La forma mas sencilla que tengo de hacer una busqueda es con una simple función para luego consumirla y retornar en la respuesta del servicio o leer directamente la consola:

```
const Usuario = require('../UsuarioSchema');

prueba = async () => {
    const usuario = await Usuario.find();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(usuario));
}
```

Comment: Si, tengo datos en la base de datos, eso es lo mas extraño de todo, el servidor si esta funcionando, si cambio todo y dejo de usar Mongoose y uso Mongodb me funciona a la perfeccion

Comment: Te aseguraste de importar el Schema y ponerle de nombre Usuario y no UsuarioSchema. Fijate que tu schema se llama UsuarioSchema pero en el find le ponés Usuario (`Usuario.find()`)

Comment: Acabo de notar que al Schema lo exportas como **usuario** pero luego lo consumis como **U**suario. Probaste si eso tiene algo que ver?

Comment: Otra cosa, en tu console log de retorno trata de cambiarlo a esto `console.log(JSON.stringify(respuesta))` dado que la respuesta viene en formato JSON y no lo va a poder interpretar la consola. No es la causa de tu problema pero ya vas mitigando algo.

Comment: Otra consideración a validar: los campos del schema se corresponden con los de la base? A veces los problemas están en las cosas simples